# How to change a CSS attribute by changing a global variable?

Tags: javascript, css, variables, attributes, global-variables

I've got a button that when pressed changes a variable between true and false. When true I want the test to display blue, when false I want the text to display black. I'm not sure why but the text is staying blue, despite the variable changing. Here's my code:

```
<div id="test1">Hello</div>
<button onclick="change()">Change</button>

<script>

var swap = true;
function change(){
    if(swap === true){
        swap = false;
    }
    else{
        swap = true;
    }

    document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = swap;  
}

if(swap === true){
    document.getElementById("test1").style.color = "blue";
}

else if(swap === false){
    document.getElementById("test1").style.color = "black";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Because the code to change the text color is only executed when the page loads. You need to move the code to set the color into the change() method.

Answer (score 1):

Because the style change isn't within the function, so it is called once on page load but not when the button is clicked. Try moving the if/else condition within the function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get rid of the if and else if statement and put the logic in the change() function.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xtofb5om/1/)**

```
var swap = true;

function change() {
    if (swap === true) {
        swap = false;
        document.getElementById("test1").style.color = "black";
    } else {
        swap = true;
        document.getElementById("test1").style.color = "blue";
    }

    document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = swap;
}
```